# Component dll failed to load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've just installed Visual Studio 2012 Pro and I'm getting `A component dll failed to load....`

I've reinstalled, made sure I have all the .net frameworks... I do not know where to go from here! Please Help

Here is a image of the error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing VS2012 on drive other then the C: can cause issues if you've had a installation on the C drive prior to this installation.

In my scenario I had the VS2012 RC installed on my C drive, but when I installed the retail release, and chose to install to my D drive (after uninstalling the RC version) some settings were not reset properly.

Uninstalling and re-installing on the C drive fixed the problem.

Comment: It is recommended to install Beta or RC bits only on a crash-burn virtual machine, which you can throw away later, because it is rather difficult to uninstall them cleanly and prepare for RTM installation.